# Обновление значения параметра Text и(или) Input

Tags: python, pysimplegui

[image: Мы видим 6 sg.text-ов у каждого из них должен быть параметр visible. Мне бы хотелось для каждого из них значение этого параметра записать в переменную, например visible = vsq5. При введении в input числа от 2 до 6 должны выводиться эти text-a, количественно равные значению введенному в input. Подскажите как это сделать и возможно ли это? Заранее спасибо!]
Мы видим 6 sg.text-ов у каждого из них должен быть параметр visible. Мне бы хотелось для каждого из них значение этого параметра записать в переменную, например visible = vsq5. При введении в input числа от 2 до 6 должны выводиться эти text-a, количественно равные значению введенному в input. Подскажите как это сделать и возможно ли это? Заранее спасибо!

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: Если я вас правильно понял. так сделайте вот так: уберите в строчке 'Уравнение .. '.  Оставьте лишь настройки и название переменной
sg.Text(Justification, size, key='a').

Например так. И внизу, опишите условие... если у вас key ( inputa) как раз равен такому-то значение, то выводите key='a'. И так по всем числам в зависимости от значение. 
Или можно по-другому.... одна строчка с  
sg.Text('Уравнение', sg...... (всякие опции по оформлению), key='a'),

Ниже ввести такое:
window['a].update('Уравнение' + str(Число из инпута от 2 до 6))

Comment: @Volk, Не совсем то как я себе это представлял, но ваш ответ помог мне разобраться, спасибо большое!

Answer (score 0):

смотри, ты можешь присвоить аргумент key к каждому из Text боксов и управляться с ними как тебе захочется через window['key1'].update(result), где key1 название ключа для определенного Text бокса, а result то, что ты хочешь вывести
Я может не совсем понял задание, но с помощью ключей ты можешь напрямую управлять содержимым Text, читая значение из Input
Условно:
Ты ввел в Input, ключ которого key1, 123 и хочешь, чтобы оно появилось в боксе Text с ключом key2 при нажатии кнопки с названием 'Показать', то часть кода будет примерно такой:

```
window.read()
if event == 'Показать':
    window['key2'].update(values['key1'])
```

А вообще для ознакомления с обновлением боксов Text есть отдельная программа в PSGDemos
Если ты на линуксе, то просто в терминале напиши psgdemos и откроется окошко с выбором примеров, где тебе нужна будет программа с названием: Demo_Design_Pattern_Persistent_Window.py
Или можешь найти на их сайте cookbook по этой ссылке [Cookbook](https://www.pysimplegui.org/en/latest/cookbook/#recipe-pattern-2b-persistent-window-multiple-reads-using-an-event-loop-updates-data-in-window)